# Null pointer with Firebase auth. How to put listener to another class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Trying to implement firebase auth. It was working before but after refactoring no.
So I tried to create authStateListener in a separate class and there I am checking the statement. 
MainActivity

```
IMainPresenter iMainPresenter;
        iMainPresenter = new MainPresenter();
        iMainPresenter.forwardInfoForLoginAuth(MainActivity.this);
```

In presenter

```
public class MainPresenter implements IMainPresenter{

    AuthStateListenerUtil authStateListenerUtil;

    public MainPresenter() {
        this.authStateListenerUtil = authStateListenerUtil;
    }

    @Override
    public void forwardInfoForLoginAuth(Activity mainActivity) {
        AuthStateListenerUtil authStateListenerUtils = new AuthStateListenerUtil();
        authStateListenerUtils.checkForAuthState(mainActivity);
    }
}
```

And the class which has to check the state of the user and in case that user is not logged in it has to show login window

```
public void checkForAuthState(final Activity mainActivity){
    Log.v("==========>", " IN CHECK FOR METHOD");

    new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (FirebaseUserUtil.currentUser != null) {
                //Create new user
                final String userName = FirebaseUserUtil.currentUser.getDisplayName();
                FirebaseUserUtil.getCurrentUserUid(FirebaseUserUtil.userUid)
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            //the image is still the default one
                            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                            userMap.put("name", userName);
                            userMap.put("image", "default");
                            userMap.put("thumb_image", "default");
                            userMap.put("status", "Your status is here...");
                            FirebaseUserUtil.getCurrentUserUid(FirebaseUserUtil.userUid).setValue(userMap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });

            } else {
                mainActivity.startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I am trying to initialize all main queries in one class to avoid duplicating on each activity. In future I will refactor it to dagger2 but right now I am using regular classes. So thats the query class

```
public class FirebaseUserUtil {

   public static FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   public static String currentUserUid = currentUser.getUid();

    public static DatabaseReference getCurrentUserUid(){
        return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserUid);
    }

    static String getCurrentUserUidString(String uid){
        String currentUid = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserUid).toString();
        return currentUid;
    }

}
```

In logs it shows me tag "IN CHECK FOR METHOD" so I made a conclusion that threw presenter it finds this method but it crashes. Also, I thought that it might be a problem with firebase database. So I removed everything from there. So if I understand right if the table in firebase is empty after user login it has to create a new table with data. Also the problem is that error which I can see in logcat don't give me a link or information where is the mistake.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.borisruzanov.russianwives, PID: 6777
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.auth.zzi.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

My App class

```
public class App extends Application{

    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        /* Picasso */

        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
        builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        Picasso built = builder.build();
        built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

            mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

            mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot != null) {

                        mUserDatabase.child("online").onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }


    }


}
```

For me it looks like that the error is in Database not in code.

Comment: The code you posted for `checkForAuthState()` creates an AuthStateListener:  `new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()`, but is not added to any instance of `FirbaseAuth` and will never be called.  Have you posted the right code?

Comment: @BobSnyder yes that the code I use. I have tried the same code in main activity. Everything works. So I guess that means that I have to add some instance?

Comment: The crash indicates that somewhere in your code you are adding a listener with a call to `addAuthStateListener()`.  I don't see that call anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @BobSnyder I added app class which extends the application. I think the problem there. After your words I remind about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your behavior it's the same for all user state changes you've to use "addAuthStateListener".

For AuthStateListener works you have to execute some of methods to authenticate ("signInWithEmailAndPassword", "createUserWithEmailAndPassword", ...).

The best way to implement a FirebaseAuth is keeping an instance in your Presenter or Interactor of that object and program the same code block for all:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
public MainPresenter() {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            /* 
             *  put your code here
             */
        }
    });
 }
```

Or addOnCompleteListener for each method of authentication (in this case signInWithEmailAndPassword).

```
 public void login(String email, String password){

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                 .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        if (user!=null) {
                            listener.onResult(null, user);
                        }
                    } else {
                        listener.onResult(task.getException(), null);
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            listener.onResult(e, null);
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the floowing line of code:

```
new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {/* ... */}
```

It means that you are creating a new instance of `AuthStateListener` class but without assignin it to a variable.

So it gives you a `NPE` because you using `addAuthStateListener()` on an object that has the value of `null`. To solve this, just asign `new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()` to you `mAuth` field and then use it wherever you want.